# Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array [CORE\cake\libs\view\helpers\paginator.php, line 194]

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I have a table of users' details (first name, last name etc). I am trying to use the cakephp's paginator helper to have links on the fields instead of just plain text so that the viewer can sort the fields in any direction he/she may want to. I am getting this warning 'Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array [CORE\cake\libs\view\helpers\paginator.php, line 194]'.
In my controller I have used the following code:

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
  var $name = 'Users';
  var $helpers = array('Html','Form', 'Paginator');
  var $paginate = array( 
    'limit' => 30,
    'order' => array(
        'User.user_ID' => 'asc'
    )
);
}
```

In the view I have used the following code:

```
$tableheaders = array($this->Paginator->sort('First Name', 'first_name', array('model' => 'User')), 
                      $this->Paginator->sort('Last Name', 'last_name', array('model' => 'User'))
                      $this->Paginator->sort('Email', 'email', array('model' => 'User')),  
                      );
echo $this->Html->tableHeaders($tableheaders);
```

I am currently using cakephp's 1.3 version framework. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: "User.user_ID" Doesnt look very conventional. Does it have to be this strange? Or could it just be (following the conventions) "User.user_id"?

Comment: Don't you miss a ',' after the second line/value of your array ?

Comment: Are you actually paginating in your controller? $this->set('data', $this->paginate('User'));